# How to filter on a Boolean column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have an sql table that contain a Boolean column.
Example `my_table`:

```
column_1   column_2  column_3 column_4
-----------------------------------------
AA         BB         CC       false
---------------------------------------
CC         FF          JJ      true
```

I want to select only `column_1` and `column_2` in condition `column_4=true` to create a new `dataset`.

My code to extract a new dataset:

```
def create_dataset(my_table):
    output = (
        my_table.select(
            F.col('column_1').alias('first_name'),
            F.col('column_2').alias('last_name'))
        .withColumn('first_name', F.when(F.col('first_name').isin(["NULL", None, ""]), None).otherwise(F.col('first_name')))
        .withColumn('last_name', F.when(F.col('last_name').isin(["NULL", None, ""]), None).otherwise(F.col('last_name')))        
    )
    return output
```

I added a filter to take the lines where I have `column_4 is true`.

my new code:

```
def create_dataset(my_table):
    output = (
        my_table.select(
            F.col('column_1').alias('first_name'),
            F.col('column_2').alias('last_name')).where("column_4"=true)
        .withColumn('first_name', F.when(F.col('first_name').isin(["NULL", None, ""]), None).otherwise(F.col('first_name')))
        .withColumn('last_name', F.when(F.col('last_name').isin(["NULL", None, ""]), None).otherwise(F.col('last_name')))        
    )
    return output
```

When I use where, I got this error:

```
keyword can't be an expression
```

How can I filter on my data according the Boolean `column_4 =true` ?
Thank you

Comment: In `"column_4"=true` the equal sign is assignment, not the check for equality. You would need to use `==` for equality. However, if the column is already a boolean you should just do `.where(F.col("column_4"))`. If it's a string, you need to do `.where(F.col("column_4")=="true")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a boolean column. Therefore, it is valid in a where clause or when clause.

```py
df.show()                                                                                                          
+---+-----+                                                                     
| id| bool|
+---+-----+
|  1| true|
|  2|false|
+---+-----+


df.printSchema()                                                                                                   
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- bool: boolean (nullable = true)


df.where("bool").show() # or df.where(F.col("bool")).show()
+---+----+
| id|bool|
+---+----+
|  1|true|
+---+----+


df.select(F.when(F.col('bool'), 'bar').otherwise("foo")).show()                                                  
+------------------------------------+                                          
|CASE WHEN bool THEN bar ELSE foo END|
+------------------------------------+
|                                 bar|
|                                 foo|
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `output_df = my_table.filter(my_table.column_4 == True).select('column_1', 'column_2')`